# Swift - Array of SCNVector4 to NSValue?

Tags: objective-c, swift, scenekit, nsvalue

How can I convert an array of vector to an NSValue? There is a convenience initiation for a single SCNVector4 for instance, but how can I use that for an array?

Like:

```
let v1 = SCNVector4(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, z: 0.0, w: 0.0)
let v2 = SCNVector4(x: 1.0, y: 0.0, z: 0.0, w: 0.0)

let value = NSValue(scnVector4: v1) // that works
let arrayValue = NSValue(scnVectors4: [v1, v2]) // that obviously doesnt work :( What will work?
```

=== context ===

I want to pass points to a shader, using a shader modifier (within SceneKit). The code in the shader is:

```
uniform vec4 u_points[7];
```

I'm trying to pass the points to the shader doing:

```
material.setValue(points, forKey: "u_points") // points is a [SCNVector4] with length 7
```

This doesn't work. If I had a single vector (`uniform vec4 u_point;`), I can do:

```
material.setValue(NSValue(vec4: points[0]), forKey: "u_point")
```

and that works. Similarly, if the shader is using an array of length 1 (ie `uniform vec4 u_points[1];`), the previous binding would also work. So it sounds like if I can pass a vector of length 4x7=28 instead of an array, I should be good

==== tries ====

1/ NSArray of NSNumber

As mentioned in the comments, `setValue` can takes anything in input, so I tried with an NSArray of NSNumber:

```
let points = [v1, v2]
let a = points.map({ return [$0.x, $0.y, $0.z] })
.flatMap({ return $0 })
  .map({ return NSNumber(value: $0) }) // a is [NSNumber] of length 2x4 = 8

material.setValue(NSArray(array: a), forKey: "u_points")
```

but that doesn't work

2/ NSArray of SCNVector3: didn't work

3/ NSArray of NSValue of SCNVector3: didn't work

4/ NSArray of NSArray of NSNumber: didn't work

It'd be great if Apple had some kind of good documentation...

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSValue_Class/: *"An NSValue object is a simple container for a single C or Objective-C data item. ..."* NSValue cannot hold an array. What are do you need it for?

Comment: Pass an array of vectors to a GL shader (`uniform vec4 u_points[7];` in my shader code) It might be possible to pass a vector 28 here instead of 7 vector 4, even though I'm not 100% sure. How would you go about creating an `NSValue` that holds those 28 values?

Comment: The docs says that NSValue can work with a pointers. Can you not have a pointer with an array?

Comment: Sure, you can pass a pointer in an NSValue, but it is *your* responsibility to guarantee the lifetime of the pointed-to data. – I am not familiar with GL shaders, so I probably cannot help here. But I would suggest that you add all relevant information about the actual use case to the question itself.

Comment: Yes, I was trying to keep the question focused, but I probably needs to add a bit

Comment: Again, I am not expert for this, but note that `setValue:forKey` does not require an NSValue argument, it takes an AnyObject. So passing an (NS)Array of NSValue might work.

Comment: Thanks. I've tried a number of combinations and filled a bug for apple documentation on that.

Comment: When you get to dealing with shader-language arrays, it's more relevant that you're passing an arbitrary bag of bytes down to the GPU than what CPU-side data type is in it. I haven't tested myself, but you might be able to try making a (Swift) `Array` of `SCNVector4`s, creating an `NSData` from that, and passing the `NSData` to the shader.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this would solve your issue, but `NSValue` can contain some fixed sized array.

```
let v1 = SCNVector4(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, z: 0.0, w: 0.0)
let v2 = SCNVector4(x: 1.0, y: 0.0, z: 0.0, w: 0.0)

let value = NSValue(scnVector4: v1) // that works
let arrayValue = NSValue(bytes: [v1, v2], objCType: "[2{SCNVector4=ffff}]")
```

Check [the reference of `NSValue` class](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsvalue), and [Type Encodings](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjCRuntimeGuide/Articles/ocrtTypeEncodings.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008048-CH100-SW1).

[init(bytes:objCType:)](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsvalue/1411621-init)

> ### Declaration
>
> ```
> init(bytes value: UnsafeRawPointer,  
>      objCType type: UnsafePointer<Int8>)
> ```
>
> Parameters
>   - value | A pointer to data to be stored in the new value object.
>
> type | The Objective-C type of value, as provided by the @encode()
>   compiler directive. ***Do not hard-code this parameter as a C
>   string.***

You may need to hard code the type, as `@encode()` directive is not available in Swift.